# How to import git repositories in a cloud function?

Tags: node.js, git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to import a library from git in my cloud function. In a *regular* node app, I do the following:

package.js

```
.
.
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^4.0.0",
    "@mylib/libname": "git+https://nierty:45Rt5jNGAtkcSANGIFO@bitbucket.org/myteam/myLibrary.git#master"
  }
.
.
```

And, then within the application, I just import the functions as needed, like below:

```
const {pubsubUtils} = require('@mylib/libname')
```

But when I deploy the cloudfunction,it throws the following error:

`Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module @mylib/libname`.

Please suggest me how to import this library from git in cloud functions

Comment: I tried to reproduce your afair but I am afraid it is not possible to import Git repositories into Cloud Functions. A good alternative would be to utilize Cloud Sources Repositories, which you could find further documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo). You will be able to deploy your function source code from a source repository when using CSR (Cloud Sources Repositories). Hope it helps.

Comment: Importing git repos is not allowed. So, I imported the library at the root of my cloud functions repo and got it working.